# Load SettingDefinitionProvider with additional properties from database

Tags: abp

I am using separate DB per Tenant. I ran into a scenario where I need to load the settings definitions from the DB.  The reason for it is each Tenant can have its own default values. So I want to copy the default values over to the new tenants created by cloning the parent tenant DB and override the default values. However, I also want to update the other fields or add new columns ex: IsVisibleToClients can change per tenant and I cannot have this value in application code but instead want it in the DB
Is this currently supported or a way to handle this

Able to override the settings but looking to save all default values to DB. I believe this can be done by creating seeding scripts.
And new tenants can be creating by cloning this DB and then override the default values. But how can I manage the fields like IsVisibleToClients per tenant and add other custom columns

Answer (score 2):

Creating Custom Setting Value Providers is explained in Abp's own documentation, you can use it.(https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Settings#custom-setting-value-providers)

```cs
public class CustomSettingValueProvider : SettingValueProvider
{
    public override string Name => "Custom";

    public CustomSettingValueProvider(ISettingStore settingStore) 
        : base(settingStore)
    {
    }

    public override Task<string> GetOrNullAsync(SettingDefinition setting)
    {
        /* Return the setting value or null
           Use the SettingStore or another data source */
    }
}
```

```cs
Configure<AbpSettingOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ValueProviders.Add<CustomSettingValueProvider>();
});
```